# Show a Verify/Wrong Picture if i have internet on computer

Tags: c#

I want to make a program that checks if the computer is connected to the internet when i start the application.

This is my [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITlOq.png)

And this is my Code:

```
private bool checkinternet()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
    WebResponse response;
    try
    {
        response = request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
        request = null;
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        request = null;
        return false;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EvenArgs e)
{
    bool checkinternet = false;
    {

    }
}
```

The code to check the internet connection works. I tried using buttons, but i want to display an image in imagebox1 if the computer has internet, or display another image if it is not connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the operation in your form load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckInternet()) // change to upper case (convention for methods)
    {
         imagebox1.Image = Image.FromFile("p://ath/to/online/image.jpg");
    }
    else
    {
         imagebox1.Image = Image.FromFile("p://ath/to/offline/image.jpg");
    }
}
```

The above code is calling your `CheckInternet` method that returns a bool value whenever there is an internet connection or not.
According to the returned value, you need to set the correct image.
You need to provide the full image path name as parameter to the Image.FromFile method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use a `using`-directive to automatically dispose your `WebRequest`:

```
private bool checkinternet()
{
    using(WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com"))
    {
        WebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also you need to call your method using braces in an `if`-statement where you need `==`to check for a value:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EvenArgs e)
{
    if(checkinternet() == false)
    {
        //no internet
    }
    if(checkinternet())
    {
        //internet
    }
    if(!checkinternet())
    {
        //no internet
    }
}
```

Finally, as stated in the answer from *ehh* you can use the `Load` event to execute the code when the Form opens:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkinternet())
    {
         imagebox1.Image = Image.FromFile("p://ath/to/online/image.jpg");
    }
    else
    {
         imagebox1.Image = Image.FromFile("p://ath/to/offline/image.jpg");
    }
}
```